# If $B = R^TR$ and $B$ is symmetric positive definite, then $R$ is invertible

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, solution-verification

I have a problem in my textbook:

Assume B is symmetric positive semi-definite. Show that $B=R^TR$ for some square matrix $R$ that is not necessarily symmetric, and that if $B$ is symmetric positive definite, then $R$ is invertible.

My approach:

Since $B$ is PSD and symmetric, it is diagonalizable, so we can write $B=V\Lambda V^T$.

So, $B=V\Lambda V^T = B=V\Lambda^{1/2}\Lambda^{1/2} V^T = (\Lambda^{1/2}V^T)^T\Lambda^{1/2}V^T=R^TR$ for $R=\Lambda^{1/2}V^T$

Now, for the second part, i'm not quite sure if i'm doing it right:

If $B$ is PD, then all eigenvalues are positive. Hence,

$R= \begin{bmatrix} v_{11}\sqrt{\lambda_1} & 0 &...&0 \\ 0 & v_{22}\sqrt{\lambda_2} & ... & 0\\0 &...&...&v_{nn}\sqrt{\lambda_n}  \end{bmatrix}$

And it has an inverse:

$R^{-1}= \begin{bmatrix} 1/v_{11}\sqrt{\lambda_1} & 0 &...&0 \\ 0 & 1/v_{22}\sqrt{\lambda_2} & ... & 0\\0 &...&...&1/v_{nn}\sqrt{\lambda_n}  \end{bmatrix}$

With which $R^{-1}R=I_n$. Hence, $R$ is invertible.

I am not sure whether the second part is rigorous, or if it's even correct. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost right, but $R = \Lambda^{1/2} V^\top$ is not diagonal.

Since $V^\top$ is invertible, it suffices to show $\Lambda^{1/2}$ is invertible to conclude that $R$ is invertible. Since the eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ are positive, we know $\Lambda^{1/2}$ is diagonal with positive diagonal entries, and can be inverted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For some crazy reason I thought $R$ was diagonal. Why is $V^T$ invertible? Is this some property?

Comment: @Marina Because $B$ is symmetric, it is not only diagonalizable, but it is also diagonalizable by an orthonormal basis. So $V$ is orthogonal and $V^{-1} = V^\top$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $R = UDV^T$ be SVD of $R$ such as $U$ and $V$ are unitary matrices ($V^TV = 1$ and $U^TU = 1$). Then, $B=R^TR = VD^2V^T$. Since B is PSD, it is non-singular and all entries of $D^2$ are nonzero (you can also compute determinant: $det(D^2) = det(B) > 0$). Therefore, R is also non-singular ($det(R) = det(D) \neq 0$) and it's inverse is $R^{-1} = VD^{-1}U^T$